# How to accurately estimate air-entry value (AEV) suction for soils?

Tags: hydrology, soil-science, hydrogeology

In the literature, there are graphical (approximate) ways to estimate AEV from the soil water retention curve. I wonder, how can one more accurately estimate AEV according to its definition: the suction value at the transition from a saturated to an unsaturated state.

Assuming one has volumetric water content (VWC) vs. suction measurements from laboratory tests (HYPROP test), how can we leverage these values to estimate AEV?

Is it sensible to choose the suction value corresponding to the second largest VWC as the AEV?